# Method signature is same as arguments - Still throwing argument matcher error

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

```
@Test
public void checkSFCaseExist_success_listIsNull_size0() {
    when(salesForceServiceClient.getCaseNumberByContactInfoAndBatchDate(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(isNull());
    ResponseDto responseDto = manualRiskCasePipeline.checkSFCaseExist(ParameterVO.merchantAccountNumber, ParameterVO.merhantRealmId,
            ParameterVO.email, ParameterVO.batchDate, ParameterVO.authHeader);
    assertNotNull(responseDto);
    assertTrue(responseDto.getErrorMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("IBOSS risk case does not exist."));

}
```

Consider this test method, when I run this I get:

```
    Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at com.intuit.v4.money.risk.ibossdecisionsvcapp.ManualRiskCasePipelineTest.checkSFCaseExist_success_listIsNull_size0(ManualRiskCasePipelineTest.java:94)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(any(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(any(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
, mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@d6e13404 testClass = ManualRiskCasePipelineTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.intuit.v4.money.risk.ibossdecisionsvcapp.DecisionManagementApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@20e4cffb key = [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@b633534b, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@d0aa100c, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@ebaded47, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@fe25c728, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@686fa9d6, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@2a2c1dcb, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@75101db0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@fa98e00, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@1a73b6b], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.populatedRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.resetRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false, 'org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.mocks' -> org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine$$Lambda$323/0x0000000000000000@922ea4de]] 

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
```

I get this on line:

```
when(salesForceServiceClient.getCaseNumberByContactInfoAndBatchDate(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(isNull());
```

The corrosponding method declaration is anigned with argument matchers:

```
List<String> getCaseNumberByContactInfoAndBatchDate(CaseSearchDO var1, String var2, String var3);
```

Why I am getting this stubbing error, I am using SpringBoot & Mockito. When I change to         when(salesForceServiceClient.getCaseNumberByContactInfoAndBatchDate(any(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(isNull());
then also I get same. Very wierd.

Comment: Have you tried using thenReturn(null) instead of isNull() in the when block? like this `when(salesForceServiceClient.getCaseNumberByContactInfoAndBatchDate(any(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(null);`

Comment: Or simple remove this line, because return null is default behaviour for mock

Comment: `thenReturn(isNull())` doesn't make any sense. What is `isNull()`? If it is the argument matcher from Mockito, that's wrong (argument matchers can only be used in the call part when stubbing). If it's a custom method, please show its implementation.